# Interesting HashMap implementation (build 1.7.0_25-b17)

Tags: java, android, hashmap, libgdx

I have developed a garbage collector friendly String cache for my Android game. Its purpose is to handle Strings for ints. I made a silly mistake implementing it but the bug never disclosed itself in desktop. In Android, however, the cache started returning funny Strings at once:

```
class IntStringCache {

private final Map<IntStringCache.IntCacheKey, String> cachedStrings = new HashMap<IntStringCache.IntCacheKey, String>();
private final IntCacheKey tempIntCacheKey = new IntCacheKey(0);

public String getStringFor(int i) {
    tempIntCacheKey.setIntValue(i);
    String stringValue = cachedStrings.get(tempIntCacheKey);
    if (stringValue == null) {
        stringValue = String.valueOf(i);
        // ERROR - putting the same object instead of new IntCachKey(i)
        cachedStrings.put(tempIntCacheKey, stringValue);
    }
    return stringValue;
}

public int getSize() {
    return cachedStrings.size();
}

private class IntCacheKey {

    private int intValue;

    private IntCacheKey(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    private void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
        result = prime * result + intValue;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        IntCacheKey other = (IntCacheKey) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
            return false;
        if (intValue != other.intValue)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private IntStringCache getOuterType() {
        return IntStringCache.this;
    }

}
```

And the tests all of which pass:

```
public class IntStringCacheTest {

private IntStringCache intStringCache = new IntStringCache();

@Test
public void shouldCacheString() {
    // given
    int i = 1;

    // when
    String s1 = intStringCache.getStringFor(i);
    String s2 = intStringCache.getStringFor(i);

    // then
    assertThat(s1).isNotNull();
    assertThat(s1).isEqualTo(String.valueOf(i));
    assertThat(s1).isSameAs(s2);
}

@Test
public void shouldCacheTwoValues() {
    // given
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    int expectedCacheSize = 2;

    // when
    String s1 = intStringCache.getStringFor(i1);
    String s2 = intStringCache.getStringFor(i2);

    // then
    assertThat(intStringCache.getSize()).isEqualTo(expectedCacheSize);
    assertThat(s1).isSameAs(intStringCache.getStringFor(i1));
    assertThat(s2).isSameAs(intStringCache.getStringFor(i2));
}
```

}

Note:

```
    assertThat(String.valueOf(1)).isSameAs(String.valueOf(1));
```

fails.

The fact that the second test passes is interesting as, with the bug, there should be one key in the map that gets updated. This may be explained with hashCode() that could make the same key go into two different buckets inside HashMap. But how is it possible that the same key (even if in two buckets) returns the same two Stings? It seems that even though there is a bug in the code the HashMap does the job correctly.

My Android Java implementation, on the other hand, returns wrong number Strings with this bug at once.

Comment: Why did you have to create the IntCacheKey class? I fail to see why that is different than a simple Integer.

Comment: If you have an int and put it into HashMap it turns into Integer. What happens if you call hashmap.get(int)? Doesn't it get autoboxed to Integer? If so, it gets garbage collected and that is what I want to avoid. I didn't check it and I may be wrong about the autoboxing with get().

Comment: Well, after a quick though: it has to get autoboxed since hashCode() and equals() are called to find the Integer in the map.

Comment: I would not bother about GC until it is proven that you have issues because of it. However, the HashMap itself is an issue: Over time, it just grows and grows. Integer.toString is not that costly comparede to how much trouble this cache causes. I'd say, this is a fortunate case of a real life example why premature optimization the root cause of evil is....

Comment: Do you mean GC in general or GC calls during game screen rendering?

Comment: GC in general. And performance in general too. While development must always be done with keeping these in mind, but I'd say only solve a problem when it is proven to exist...

Comment: I agree with the general approach. However, GC in Android game screen rendering is a different issue. Each time GC kicks in, your FPS ratio may drop a couple of frames causing a visible slow down effect.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't want to use the LibGDX IntMap? It's main reason for existing is to avoid the autoboxing of HashMap<Integer, ?>.

Comment: My first idea was not to make the code too lib dependent but I don't think I will use anything else than libgdx. I think I will start using libgdx collections API.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider replacing this entire class with [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) or its Support Library equivalent [SparseArrayCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SparseArrayCompat.html) (if you need it on <3.0 devices) as they are specifically designed to map integers to objects in a memory efficient way.

Comment: Thanks, libgdx also has some collections of that sort so that you can use the code in different envs. But nobody so far answered my question: what happens with the HashMap implementation? It is extra dangerous since the tests don't catch that issue.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured that out. The key in the HashMap is the same for both entries but stored on two different lists because of hashCode(). Later, when you change the int in the key, hashCode() is used again to find the bucket first. It finds the right one. Even though the code is broken it works.